# udev rules for device mapper when lvm volumes are activated

Tags: udev, lvm2, device-mapper

I currently have a couple of custom udev rules for activating LVM volumes when raid volumes become available that look like this:

```
KERNEL=="md0", RUN+="/sbin/pvscan --cache -aay"
KERNEL=="md1", RUN+="/sbin/pvscan --cache -aay"
```

is it possible to something similar to mount at a fixed mount point for the LVM volumes when they become available. I'm assuming I must match a device mapper event, but I cannot find any documentation on how to do that so I'm wondering if it's even possible.

Please provide links to documentation one way or the other

Comment: Take a read through this post and see some of the comments—a few of them I think about half way down and others towards the bottom—that may be applicable for what you are asking for: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/make-removable-usb-hdd-mount-at-fixed-mount-point-511917/. Tag me back if you think any of this is helpful for maybe even a starting point. I think you are asking once the RAID shows the disk then you want to mount to LVM on those, etc.

Comment: @McDonald's It's once the LVM is visible, how can I mount those. Once those lines pvscan run, and an LVM volume can be built, you'll see /dev/dm-0 or /dev/dm-1 or whatever. I'd like to mount those as soon as they appear using a udev rule (that's compatible with systemd as I'm on Debian Jessie).

Comment: Check out some of these answers.... https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11125/lvm-devices-under-dev-mapper-missing . . . Does this look more like something you are needing? I'm not a Linux expert and just trying to give you some pointers for potentially helpful content to help you get a sufficient solution. And one other thing I just found just in case: https://www.redhat.com/archives/linux-lvm/2014-July/msg00011.html

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention your distribution so I'll do it as general as possible.

First let me quote the documentation the [udisk2 api docs](http://storaged.org/doc/udisks2-api/2.6.5/gdbus-org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Block.html) ([udisk2 api MDRaid](http://storaged.org/doc/udisks2-api/2.6.5/gdbus-org.freedesktop.UDisks2.MDRaid.html#gdbus-interface-org-freedesktop-UDisks2-MDRaid.top_of_page)):

> The "Id" property
>
> Id  readable   s
>
> A unique and persistent identifier for the device or blank if no such
>   identifier is available.
>
> For devices with fixed media, this identifier is derived from vital
>   product data / UUIDs / serial numbers of the drive or construct (e.g.
>   LVM or MD-RAID) the block device is part of. For devices with
>   removable media, this identifier is derived from the medium currently
>   inserted.
>
> This identifier is guaranteed to not include the slash character '/'
>   (U+002F SOLIDUS) which means it can be used as a filename.
>
> Examples: “by-id-ata-INTEL_SSDSA2MH080G1GC_CVEM842101HD080DGN”,
>   “by-id-ata-ST1000LM024_HN-M101MBB_S2TBJA0C230233-part3”,
>   “by-id-usb-Kingston_DataTraveler_2.0_0013729940C4F9A166250D3E-0:0”,
>   “by-id-dm-name-luks-6d81fe85-26b1-4f8b-b834-405454c1cd46”,
>   “by-id-dm-name-vg_thinkpad-lv_swap”,
>   “by-label-HARRY_POTTER_SORCERERS_STONE-”, “by-uuid-D22D-08B8”.
>
> Since 2.0.0

First you have to get all the ID's running: `udevadm info /dev/sr0 | grep ID`

An example of such mount:
    /etc/udev/rules.d/99-mount_raid.rules

```
 # to create mount-points and mount devices
  KERNEL=="md0", ENV{ID}=="by-id-dm-name-luks-6d81fe85-26b1-4f8b-b834-405454c1cd46", ACTION=="add", ENV{mount_options}="relatime", RUN+="/bin/mkdir -p /media/md0_raid", RUN+="/bin/mount -o $env{mount_options} /dev/%k /media/md0_raid"
```

note: `%k` - The "kernel name" for the device more at [udev man](https://linux.die.net/man/8/udev)

For the udev & udisk2 I have used [udev arch linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/udev#Some_devices.2C_that_should_be_treated_as_removable.2C_are_not)

I don't have now access to a RAID DEV env, so I'm writing it from my head and links so please try it out and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: This isn't really what I'm after. Please see my other comment below the question. Distribution is debian jessie which uses systemd.

Comment: @nwaltham I'm afraid I don't then understand what you need.  To quote you: "I'd like to mount those as soon as they appear using a udev rule (that's compatible with systemd as I'm on Debian Jessie)."   I have written such rule, which you can combine with your LVM udev rule - if you run you pvscan rule before then you will be able to mount it using the udev rule I have written.

Comment: with LVM, after the pvscan runs, you'd need to mount /dev/dm-* or whatever and not /dev/md0 which you're rule would do. Thanks anyway.